# File Upload Failed using SIRIS

Tags: http, go, file-upload, go-iris

I want to upload a file to the server using SIRIS and Postman.

**Go Program**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-siris/siris"
)

func main() {
    app := siris.New()
    app.Post("/", handleFileUpload)
    app.Run(siris.Addr(":8080"))
}

func handleFileUpload(ctx siris.Context) {
    ctx.Writef("Hello<br/>")
    file, info, err := ctx.FormFile("filee")
    if err != nil {
        ctx.StatusCode(iris.StatusInternalServerError)
        ctx.HTML("Error while uploading: <b>" + err.Error() + "</b>")
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fn := info.Filename
    ctx.Writef("File Name: " + fn)
}
```

**Postman**

[image]

But Postman only can get the error message:

> Hello 
>   Error while uploading: **request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data**

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly hanle file upload html form should have attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

P.S. I do not recommend to use Iris.

Comment: Why doesn't you recommend use Iris?

Comment: @Kin read .https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11976798 and http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html . Although these articles are rather old, and some part may be outdated, but it is true that the iris author is very problematic person. You can google about "iris kataras" and get more information.

Comment: Yes. Many developers dislike the way author make his deals. So it's unlikely there would be a strong community around framework. So development and bug fixing would be very slow and without proper review. This way it becomes very risky to put this framework  as a basement of new project. Golang community has developed a lot of alternatives without such baggage.

Comment: Which fast Go web framework do you suggest for programming end API?

Comment: You may try [echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) or [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin). Also you may not to use framework at all - go http library is quite good and has nearly all required functions.